# Logging allocator for std::containers?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11, boost-mpl, allocator

**The X:** I need to know how much memory each part of my program is using. My program uses the C++ std library, a lot. In particular, I want to know how much memory each object is using.

**How I'm doing it:** to log the consumption of `some_vector`, just write

```
my::vector<double,MPLLIBS_STRING("some_vector")> some_vector;
```

where

```
namespace my {
  template<class T, class S>
  using vector = std::vector<T,LoggingAllocator<T,S>>;
}
```

The loggin allocator is implemented as follows:

```
template<class T, class S = MPLLIBS_STRING("unknown")> struct LoggingAllocator {
  // ... boilerplate ...

  pointer allocate (size_type n, std::allocator<void>::const_pointer hint = 0) {
    log_allocation(boost::mpl::c_str<S>::value);
    // allocate_memory (I need to handle it myself)
  }
  void destroy (pointer p) ; // logs destruction
  void deallocate (pointer p, size_type num); // logs deallocation
};
```

**Question:** Is there a better way to get this behavior in a generic way? By better I mean, simpler, nicer, without dependencies on `boost::mpl` and `mpllibs::metaparse`,... Ideally I would just like to write

```
my::vector<double,"some_vector"> some_vector;
```

and be done with it.

Comment: That already seems pretty generic to me, what more generic do you want?

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but if only the developers need to know memory usage it would be better to use memory profiling, than to instrument the whole codebase.

Comment: @daramarak: it depends, really, on what you want and what tools you can use; as much as I like Massif, for example, it's not like you can use it in Production, whereas a simple logger may be possible.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I think it's generic too, but the whole metaparse and boost::mpl dependencies are something to consider. I was hoping there was a simpler way to do this that wouldn't depend on metaparse/boost::mpl. I'll update the question with this.

Comment: @daramarak users need too. Its an HPC application and our users are also developers. But nice tip! Thanks! Also consider threadspotter, scalasca, and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While maybe not "more generic", if you don't want to handle all the allocation yourself, you could inherit from the standard allocator [`std::allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator):

```
template<class T, class S = MPLLIBS_STRING("unknown"), class Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
struct LoggingAllocator : public Allocator {
    // ...
};
```

In the `allocate`/`destroy`/`deallocate` functions do the logging, and then call the parents methods:

```
pointer allocate (size_type n, std::allocator<void>::const_pointer hint = 0) {
    log_allocation(boost::mpl::c_str<S>::value);
    return Allocator::allocate(n, hint);
}
```

However note that `std::allocator` isn't really designed for being inherited, exemplified by it having no virtual destructor.

Comment: Nice! This doesn't apply to my case cause I need to handle the memory allocation my self, but this just gave me the idea to abstract the logging policy :D I was trying to make it simpler tho :D

Comment: If you inherit from another allocator, it's critical that you create a new version of 'rebind', so that if the allocator's type is rebound, it returns your allocator, and not the one you inherited from

Comment: Since allocators are copied by value the lack of virtual destructor isn't a problem. You might get sliced (especially if the base allocator defines `rebind` and the derived one doesn't) but the correct destructor will run

Comment: @DaveS, +1, although note that in C++11 defining `rebind` is optional, so a derived class only needs to do it if the base class does. If the base class doesn't provide `rebind` then `std::allocator_traits<A>::rebind_alloc` will do the right thing.  But since `std::allocator` does define `rebind` you're absolutely right it's needed in this case